# Mongoose - query subdocument ID using aggregate framework

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a data set, as follows:

```
db.running.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("59960ba78fe25d08f4664d6a"),
    "person" : "Peter",
    "place" : "State Street",
    "eventDate" : ISODate("2017-08-17T00:00:00Z"),
    "thing" : "Running",
    "details" : {
            "distance" : "2 miles",
            "area" : "City Center",
            "_id" : ObjectId("599636f8ea4d7835be869728")
        }
    })
```

I am trying to run a query using `aggregate` that finds the subdocument based on its `id`. Here is the shell code that works correctly:

```
db.running.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$details'},
    { $match: {'details._id': ObjectId("599636f8ea4d7835be869728") } },
    { $project: {'thing': 0}}
]).pretty()
```

Using mongoose, my code looks like this:

```
var Running = mongoose.model('Running');
mongoose.set('debug', true);

var sendJSONresponse = function(res, status, content) {
  res.status(status);
  res.json(content);
};

module.exports.getPageGradedData = function (req, res){
    Running
        .aggregate([
            { $unwind: '$details'},
            { $match: {'details._id': req.params.detailid } },
            { $project: {'thing': 0}}
        ])
        .exec(function(err, response) {
            sendJSONresponse(res, 200, response);
    });
};
```

However, the debug from `mongoose` shows the query that `mongoose` is sending to `mongoDB` to look like this:

```
Mongoose: running.aggregate([ { '$unwind': '$details' }, { '$match': { 'details._id': '599636f8ea4d7835be869728' } }, { '$project': { thing: 0 } } ], {})
```

Mongoose clearly doesn't understand that the `details._id` object needs to be transformed to an `ObjectId`, but I'm not sure how to get it to understand that.

Comment: It doesn't appear that `details` is an array of subdocuments so why are you unwinding it and not simply matching on the full path? If your mongoose schema has typed it as an ObjectId, then it should work fine. What does the associated `Running` schema look like?

Comment: Why do you need an aggregation for this action? Looks to me like it can be solved with a simple 'find' query and projection.